# How can I create a multiple buttons in tkinter that change the background image when hovering over them?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am coding a GUI for a Mathematics Formula Calculator. I want to create multiple buttons that change the background image when hovering over them, and I don't really know how to go about doing that...

I have already tried creating a class for the button itself so that I can modify the behaviour of it, it did not work...

```
import tkinter as tk

class HoverButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, **kw):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master=master,**kw)
        self.defaultbackground = tk.PhotoImage(file = "GeometricBackground.png")
        self.currentbackground = tk.PhotoImage(file = "")
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, currentbackground):
        image = tk.Label(self, image = currentbackground)
        image.pack()
        

    def on_leave(self):
        image = tk.Label(self, image = self.defaultbackground)
        image.pack()    

root = tk.Tk()

classButton = HoverButton(root, currentbackground = "MainMenu.png")
classButton.grid()

root.mainloop()
```

I was really hoping this would cut it, but I got this error message when it executed:

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-currentbackground"
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

- The error you get is because you are trying to pass the `currentbackground` option to your `HoverButton` but given the way your class is defined:

  ```
  def __init__(self, master, **kw):
      tk.Button.__init__(self, master=master,**kw)
  ```

  `currentbackground` ends into the `kw` dictionary you pass in argument to the standard tkinter `Button` class which has no `currentbackground` option, hence the unknown option error. To fix it, you can define the options specific to your class like

  ```
  def __init__(self, master, defaultbackground="", currentbackground="", **kw):
      tk.Button.__init__(self, master=master, **kw)
  ```

  so that `defaultbackground` and `currentbackground` won't end in the `kw` dictionary.
- When an event occurs, the function you bound to this event is executed with one argument, the "event" object that contains information about the event (like the pointer coordinates, the widget in which the event happened ...) so you need to add this argument when you define `on_enter()` and `on_leave()`.
- You are creating a label to put the image inside then packing this label in the button. This is overly complicated (and probably will result in the button not reacting to click events). The button class has an `image` option to set the background image of the button, so you can change the image with `button.configure(image=<image>)`.

Inserting all those changes in the code gives

```
import tkinter as tk

class HoverButton(tk.Button):
    def __init__(self, master, defaultbackground="GeometricBackground.png", currentbackground="", **kw):
        tk.Button.__init__(self, master=master, **kw)
        self.defaultbackground = tk.PhotoImage(file=defaultbackground)
        self.currentbackground = tk.PhotoImage(file=currentbackground)
        self.configure(image=self.defaultbackground)
        self.bind("<Enter>", self.on_enter)
        self.bind("<Leave>", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, event):
        self.configure(image=self.currentbackground)

    def on_leave(self, event):
        self.configure(image=self.defaultbackground)

root = tk.Tk()
classButton = HoverButton(root, currentbackground="MainMenu.png")
classButton.grid()
root.mainloop()
```